# Is this the meaning of "bring in" in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context

The following context is a [definition from the longman dictionary](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/broadside):

> **broadside** *adverb*
> with the longest side facing something; SYNONYM: sideways
> **broadside to**
> I brought the boat in **broadside to** the beach.

Is this a correct def for the phrase **bring in** here:

1. To move or guide something or someone into some place: Please bring in the newspaper before you close the door. I brought my child in to wait with me in my office.(source thefreedictionary)

Edit: I was confused because the example-sentence doesn't state **where** the boat is brought.(only in which direction to the beach the boat is positioned) Also maybe subconsciously I knew the idiomatic definition, you(Andy) mentioned, meaning "To dock the boat". But the definition in question doesn't mention any docking area such as a pier or wharf. Is this the meaning here or why can't really tell from this example if it means to dock or leave the boat in an undetermined place?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: That seems like a good definition for this usage. It's also particularly idiomatic of boats and ships: "Bring her in" means "Dock the boat." If you can edit to tell why you have some hesitation about this definition, maybe there can be more substantial answers.

Comment: broadside and bring in have not related in your question. FYI, boats can be docked broadside or endwise.

Comment: It says it was brought in broadside _to the beach_. Boats are sometimes left on the beach instead of being docked.